# How to append String at particular index in an array of Strings

Tags: java, string, append, arrays

I have a `String` array like below:

```
String[] titles = new String[] { "Booking", "Entry", "Type",
                    "Duration", "Status", "Contract ID",
                    "Capacity", "Start Day", "End Day", "Source Ref" };
```

I need to append, some more values to this array at later state, like below:

```
titles = new String[] { "Booking", "Shipper", "Booking Quantity", "Entry", 
                        "Type", "Duration", "Status", 
                        "Contract ID", "Capacity", "Start Day", 
                        "End Day", "Source Ref" };
```

here I added `"Shipper", "Booking Quantity"` to the first array.

Is there any way to append those values based on index or any way, without creating like above example? (Is it possible?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you initialize  an array like this

```
String[] titles = new String[] { "Booking", "Entry", "Type",
                "Duration", "Status", "Contract ID",
                "Capacity", "Start Day", "End Day", "Source Ref" };
```

Property of array **"once you initialize the array after that you can't change the size of array"***
so in your case you must initialize new array ....
Or you can use `ArrayList`  and with its `add(index, value)` method you can add your value at your required 
position ..
But implicit  it also use `Concept of Dynamic Array..`

Comment: +1 for Property of array line. which should be the reason for not using array

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I didn't get right your question, but you can use `ArrayList<String>` instead of simple arrays. You can do something like this:

```
titles.add(1, "Shipper");
titles.add(2, "Book Quantity");
```

So you basically add to the `ArrayList<String>` of titles the two new elements at position 1 and 2.

And no, you can't do that with normal arrays.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't. Arrays are not dynamic. You need to create a new array. Size must be know before creating the array.

```
String[] strings = new String[titles.length + 2];
strings[0] = "Booking";
strings[1] = "Shipper";
//...
```

Answer (score 3):

To add them based on index you would actually need to create a new array and map all of the value from the old array and add the new values in as you go.

It would be much easier if you were using an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), which has an `insert` method that can insert new values at any index in the List

ex:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add("Booking");
myList.add("Entry");
myList.add("Type");
myList.add("Duration");
myList.add("Status");
myList.add("Contract ID"); 
myList.add("Capacity");
myList.add("Start Day");
myList.add("End Day");
myList.add("Source Ref");

//insertion 
myList.add(1, "Shipper");
mylist.add(2, "Booking Quantity");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can keep your strings in `ArrayList<String>` and then use `.add(index, text)` method

Answer (score 2):

Better to  use `List<String>`  and just use `add()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ArrayList as follows:

```
ArrayList titleList = new ArrayList<String>();
titleList.add("Shipper");
titleList.add("Booking");
titleList.add("Entry");
titleList.add("Type");
titleList.add("Duration");
titleList.add("Status");
titleList.add("Contract");
titleList.add("ID");
//....
titleList.add(1,"Shipper")
titleList.add(2,"Booking quality");
```

The good thing about using ArrayList is you can use Iterator and can perform various operations like searching particular entry.